# Why I am not getting complete array after concatenation of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to solve Array question on leetcode [Array Merge Sort](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/525/inserting-items-into-an-array/3253/) and issue is that when I am running my code in online compiler i.e. JS Fiddle, Programiz, I can see the complete array after concatenation but when I am running same code on leetcode compiler getting only first array instead of complete array.

Can someone please advise where, I am facing the issue.

PFA of issue -

[Leetcode Submission Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjX0D.png) --> Here, I'm getting half array instead of complete array.

[Online Compiler Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTeZB.png) --> Here, I'm getting the complete array.

Below is my code for Leetcode Question -

```js
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
    let x = nums1.length;
    if(x !== m){
        for(let i = x; i > m; i--){
            nums1.pop(nums1[i]);
        }
    }
    return nums1.concat(nums2).sort((a,b)=> a -b);
};
console.log(merge([1,2,3,0,0,0],3,[2,5,6],3));
```

Comment: `.pop()` _removes_ the last element from the array. Try `.push(…)`

Comment: Hi @Parzh, not working. Please advise why I am not getting the correct output in leetcode when running the same code but getting the right output when running this same code in other compiler.

Comment: Why return is not working here and when I am checking with console it shows the correct answer? It seems, I'm missing something please help on this.